# History.js and Google Analytics virtual pageviews page titles

Tags: google-analytics, history.js

I'm using Google Analytics to track virtual pageviews when pushState() is executed via by History.js. Things are reporting fine, but there seems to be an error in the ordering of things.

document.title is changing after the URL changes and the pageview fires, so the information sent is not consistent. It appears with an accurate URL, but contains the title of the last page.

If I delay the pageview to be sent by 100 milliseconds, I get the correct info, but would like to avoid doing this in the future.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be updating the page title in addition to the URL as you're navigating throughout the site.

The [Single Page Application Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) developer guide goes through exactly how to properly track pages loaded via AJAX using Google Analytics.